# Как сделать разыменование по указателям из unordered_map

Tags: c++

Есть класс

```
class SuffixNode {

    private:

        BYTE value;
        std::unordered_map<int, SuffixNode*> next;

    public:

        SuffixNode(BYTE inputValue) {value = inputValue;}

        ~SuffixNode() {

          ???  

        }

    }
```

Собственно, нужно при удалении элемента проходиться по всем ссылкам next и выполнять их удаление (можно рекурсивно)

Comment: или я в 12 ночи туплю, или map хочет 2 шаблонных параметра), да и непонятен смысл хранение в мапе некстов) если можно поподробнее

Comment: @Andrey это основа для нетрадиционного суффиксного массива, если интересно

Comment: @Andrey это словарь <ключ, значение> - его можно пробежать через while (this->next.size() > 0) {delete что-то из указателей this->next.begin(); this->next.erase[this->next.begin()]}

Comment: @Andrey но хотелось бы сделать это красивее и правильнее, а не говокодить

Comment: Красиво ? Foreach с функтором ?))))

Comment: Нет, конечно, удалять по одному - не в смысле `delete`, а в смысле `erase` - это и в самом деле бессмысленный ужас. Но если хотите совсем "круто" - ну, оберните указатели в интеллектуальные типа `unique_ptr` - вообще ничего не надо будет делать, все само сделается...

Comment: @Andrey: А сколько, по-вашему, шаблонных аргументов должен требовать `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: AnT без дефолтных 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да вроде просто взять и удалить:

```
~SuffixNode()
{
  for (auto kvp : next)
    delete kvp.second;
}
```

> А если p = nullptr?

То всё будет нормально:

> A pointer to the memory block to be released, type-casted to a void*.
>   If this is a null-pointer, the function does nothing.

<sup>Источник: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete/</sup>

Comment: А если p = nullptr?

Comment: Его можно передавать в delete.

Comment: не, это крайне не рекомендуется. Первое - в старых C++ это приведет к ошибке. Второе - в новых это может привести к артефактам

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG, докажи. В стандарте чётко написано, что delete с null ничего не делает. Где конкретно будет ошибка? И какие ещё "артефакты"? Никогда не видел подобного понятия в плюсах.

Comment: в каком стандарте? Я часто читал "зависит от компилятора" В clang от Embarcadero появляется ошибка "memory access", например. В C++11 и выше этого нет и там он ничего тогда не делает. НО! На форумах и про такой случай много дискуссий на тему безопасности такого подхода

Comment: я, конечно, могу заблуждаться. Надеюсь еще кто-нибудь подскажет - как точно это происходит

Comment: @Alrott SlimRG: Никаких осмысленных "дискуссий на тему безопасности такого подхода" быть не может. Может быть лишь пустая "пионэрская" болтовня. `delete` ничего не делает с null-указателем. Никаких проблем с этим никогда не было.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Что за странный цикл? Такой range-for в `std::unordered_map` будет итерировать по *парам*. Это `delete` даже не скомпилируется.

Comment: @AnT спасибо, буду знать

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG, https://stackoverflow.com/q/4190703/4928642 - 2010 год. И я сейчас специально проверил в VS2010, которая там упоминается в одном из ответов - всё работает. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ug327.png

Comment: @AnT, вроде исправил.

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG, вроде точку надо было, а не стрелку? Исправил.